# oracle error when using imp to import a dmp which contain a blob table

Tags: oracle11g

Hi:
We are using oracle11g.

First we export the tables under a certern user using the exp command,then we try to import it in other computer:

```
imp sa/000000@db file=d:/xx.dmp fromuser=ms touser=sa
```

Then the tables under user "ms" is imported,but when it comes to the table "tab_info" which contain some "blob" column,the process is blocked,then it give the following error:

```
IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file
IMP-00027: failed to rollback partial import of previous table
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1003encountered
ORA-24909: call in progress. Current operation cancelled
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

What's the problem?

And we using the same command and same xx.dmp in another computer,it works.

What's going on?

The computer we try to import the data is hold the win server 2003 system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the import works fine on one machine, I'd compare the file sizes to make sure that the problem file isn't missing bytes.

If the file sizes are the same, is the file over 2GB?  I don't believe that Windows Server 2003 (natively) supports compressed files larger than 2GB.

This blog might help shed some light on your situation: http://oratips-ddf.blogspot.com/2007/07/cut-em-off-at-pass-or-why-is-my-piped.html .